# how to backup oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g

how i can backup oracle 10g like backup and restore in sql server ?

i want to backup tables and data

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a comprehensive backup and recovery suite which is formally called Recovery Manager but is universally known as RMAN.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14196/backrest.htm#i1004902).

Answer (score 0):

The typical term for this is 'migrate' not 'backup'.  You'll then find results in your favorite search engine to tools like:
[SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/Migration-oracle.aspx)

Comment: The OP wants backup _like_ in MS-SQL, not to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want table structures and data (no code), you can use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) package  for this.

Read up here on the various methods and their associated speed

http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2008/08/09/moving-large-amounts-of-data-between-oracle-and-sql-server-findings-and-observations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Oracle export data pump (expdp) is also good utility to take logical backup of your schema. You have very nice features with lot of flexibility in data pump. You can follow the link given below for further reading.

```
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm
```